# appwidget get current id

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I added several appwidgets on the screen. To update the widget, I need to know its id.
I could not find a method that would return the id of the current widget.
How can i get the id of the current widget?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the appwidgets in the Layout Editor? If so then the id is that in the top property box (called id). ie. appwidget, appwidget2, appwidget3.

You can then use something like

```
AppWidget myAppWidget = (AppWidget) findViewByID(R.id.appwidget);
```

to update/control your app widget. A good tutorial is here:
[iProgrammer Android Tutorial](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/android.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My problem is not related to viewes. I'm creating an appwidget (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/)